# How to get the number of images in xcassets in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, assets

Is there a way to get the number of images in the `xcassets`?
In my example it looks like that:

[image]

What is more, I want to count the files starting with `1` and `2`. So in this case it must be 4 and 6. Do you have any suggestions how to solve that?